# Php file download corrupting audio files

Tags: php, audio, download

I've been programming a file downloader with php to download some audio files (.mid, .wav, .mp3) from my webiste. The download seems to work fine, but when i try to play the downloaded file, windows media player says :

> Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.

I have looked in the files with text editing software and noticed that the "corrupted" files all have an extra line break and   "< /datalist >" at the beginning of the file :
NORMAL File

> RIFF† WAVEfmt      D¬  ±   data@ SÿSÿkÿkÿu o ÷½
>       [+eŸ0a/ô>T=êFE]JjHLJ¶P—NÊU…S‡[Y _b\‘^×[èZ"XïS3Q

CORRUPTED File:

> > 
>
> < /datalist>RIFF† WAVEfmt      D¬  ±   data@ SÿSÿkÿkÿu o÷½
>   [+eŸ0a/ô>T=êFE]JjHLJ¶P—NÊU…S‡[Y _b\‘^×[èZ"XïS3Q

When i deleted the line break and "< /datalist >" tag the audio file worked again.
Here is my file downloading script:

```
$eyr = html_entity_decode($_GET['fileUrOpening']);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$eyr); 
header('Pragma: public');
readfile($eyr);
```

It gets called from another script:

```
 $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM fichierschants WHERE chant = '$id';");
  $files = $result->num_rows;

  if ($files == 0) {
    echo '<td> There are no files for this song</td>';
  }else{

    echo '<td>';
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $files ; ++$i){
        $result->data_seek($i); 
        $eode = $result->fetch_assoc()['emplacement'];
        echo'<a href="./readingFile.php?fileUrOpening=';
        echo $eode;
        echo '"">';
        $result->data_seek($i); 
        echo $result->fetch_assoc()['emplacement']."</a> <br>";
    }
    echo'</td>';
}
```

I have tried many different proposed ways to download my files, but none of them seem to work properly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Alex.

Comment: Is that all the code you have in your download script or does it contain more code? Also, have you checked that the original files don't contain that?

Comment: That is all there is in this script, it just gets called from other scripts and gets the fileName to download

Comment: the original files work properly and dont contain that

Comment: _"it just gets called from other scripts"_ - So this script isn't called directly from the browser and there are more code that gets executed before this? Please show us all the code, starting from the beginning of the request up to the download script you've posted. You should probably also use `urldecode()` instead of `html_entity_decode()`. You should also put some validation on the `$eyr`-variable, to make sure people don't pass other files (right now, people can ask for any file on your server that PHP has read access to, to be downloaded).

Comment: I don't see you "calling" that script in the new code. There's a link though, but the HTML looks a bit wrong. This `echo '"">';` should simply be `echo '">';` (one less double quote). From the code you're showing, there's nothing that would add `</datalist>` to the beginning of the file. There must be something going on you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

`application/octet-stream` is defined as "arbitrary binary data" in RFC 2046. Maybe try using the correct header for an audio file? You could get the file mime info to determine wether you should use `Content-Type: audio/mpeg`, or the equivalent for `.wav` or `.mid`.

Also, if the script is being called from elsewhere, make sure there is no output echoing. I'm guessing there isn't or you wouldn't be able to send headers properly, but it's worth checking in your `error_log`. Datalist is an HTML tag and so it would seem to me that the tag is coming from earlier in youre script, possibly output buffered or something. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: Using `application/octet-stream` is pretty standard if you want to force a download. Setting the correct content type will often open the file in the browser instead, which isn't what you want on a download-page.

Comment: Can't say I've seen that, the Content-disposition should take care of that

Comment: Not for all browsers. This is one of those "Put-a-bunch-of-extra-headers-in-there-since-some-browsers-do-things-their-own-way". They might be better at it today, I don't know. Anyway, using `application/octet-stream` won't hurt since a download simply is sending binary data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that cleaning the output buffers:

`while (ob_get_level()) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }`

right before calling readfile(), avoided the corruption of the file!

Thankyou for all your suggestions, I also added them to my script.

Have a nice day,

Alex

Comment: So you did have more code before the one you showed us, since there's no reference to any output buttering in the code at all?

Comment: I didnt touch any of the output buffering before i just tried that code and it worked